# Rails 3.1: 'where' with multiple conditions and 'not nil' verification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to find records with multiple conditions and this is my code:

```
@calhappybd = Client.where(:user_id => current_user.id, "birth IS NOT NULL")
```

I'm trying to do this with squeel-gem, but when I try to use multiple conditions (where{(cond1)(cond2)}), but my current_user.id defined as simple string-data.

Comment: What do you mean by simple string-data?

Comment: I mean that's trying to find "current_user.id" record in the table :)

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: current_user.id: SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients"  WHERE "clients"."user_id" = "current_user"."id"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With squeel, you should be able to do something like

```
@calhappybd = Client.where{(user_id == current_user.id) & (birth != nil)}
```

Let know if you get the same error again...

**UPDATED:**

Modified the conditions above. Note the single ampersand and double equals. That works for me..

**My configuration:**

```
rails 3.1.0.rc6
squeel 0.8.8
```

Comment: Thanks, but not works :( And it must be && (not single &). With Client.where{(user_id = current_user.id) && (birth != nil)} I've get all my clients:  ←[1m←[36mClient Load (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" ←[0m
=> List of ALL clients.....

Comment: I  have one solution: @calhappybd = Client.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :birth => Date.today-666.year..Date.today). It works for me well, but it's not answer for topic question :)

Comment: From the documentation https://github.com/ernie/squeel, it clearly says you should be using single `&` for `AND` (NOT double!). So this answer seems correct to me.

Comment: Sorry for my late comment. It works now, thanks. ps. I don't know what is wrong with squeel (or with me:)), but I have errror message with single &.